# Remove/update add_image_size in Wordpress Parent theme functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a child theme from a parent theme in Wordpress. I would like to change the defined image sizes in the parent's functions.php file:

```
/* Image sizes */
add_action( 'init', 'oxygen_image_sizes' );   

/**Image sizes**/
function oxygen_image_sizes() {  
add_image_size( 'archive-thumbnail', 470, 140, true );
add_image_size( 'single-thumbnail', 470, 260, true );
add_image_size( 'featured-thumbnail', 750, 380, true );
add_image_size( 'slider-nav-thumbnail', 110, 70, true );
}
```

Here is a link that I found that seems pretty straightforward but it's not working for me.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/remove-or-update-add-image-size

Here is the code that I'm using in my child theme's functions.php file:

```
function child_theme_setup() {
add_image_size( 'archive-thumbnail', 600, 140, true );
add_image_size( 'single-thumbnail', 600, 260, true );
add_image_size( 'featured-thumbnail', 600, 380, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_setup', 11 );
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Hook `after_setup_theme` is called before `init`.

So your settings get overwritten by the settings from the parent theme.

You can also use `init` to hook into and with the higher priority (11) your setting will be used.

**OR**

You remove the `oxygen_image_sizes`-action and re add **all** the image-sizes with your own function.

Comment: So you guys are saying to use `init` instead of `after_setup_theme ` and that will solve that issue? I'm facing the same problem and I need to overwrite them.